# Unable to handle Errors at end of epoch when using tf.contrib.data.Datasets API in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-processing

I have created tfrecords as my database. The database consists of 9 different tfrecord files. The purpose was to feed in a batch of samples from the 9 databases into the model. Therefore, I have used the zip function with [TFRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/TFRecordDataset). Each sample consists of a frame along with its feature set. Hence, I need to take 8 samples from each tfrecord file, which gives a total of 72 `(features, image)` in a batch. Hence, I extracted the features alone with images as shown in the code below.

Problem: When I reach the end of the 1st epoch, the remaining data as less than 72. As a result, the data from the second epoch as added to make up a batch of 72 samples. So, this is not desigrable in my case since I am training a Recurrent neural network, so I have a state that should be consistent (Not necessary to be discussed now).

Therefore, I didn't use the repeat function, instead, tries to implement what is mentioned in https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets Under Processing multiple epochs, i.e., use for loop with try and except.

```
# Compute for 100 epochs.
for _ in range(100):
  sess.run(iterator.initializer)
  while True:
    try:
      sess.run(next_element)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
      break

  # [Perform end-of-epoch calculations here.]
```

Once I did that, I got into another problem. First here is my full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2

num_epoch = 1
batch_size = 8 # This is set to 8 since
num_threads = 9
common = "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/AffectiveComputingNew/database/"
filenames = [(common + "train_1_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_2_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_3_db.tfrecords"),
     (common + "train_4_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_5_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_6_db.tfrecords"),
     (common + "train_7_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_8_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_9_db.tfrecords")]

# Transforms a scalar string `example_proto` into a pair of a scalar string and
# a scalar integer, representing an image and its label, respectively.
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    features = {
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([432], tf.float32)
    }

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)

    # This is how we create one example, that is, extract one example from the database.
    image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    # The height and the weights are used to
    height = tf.cast(parsed_features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(parsed_features['width'], tf.int32)

    # The image is reshaped since when stored as a binary format, it is flattened. Therefore, we need the
    # height and the weight to restore the original image back.
    image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, 3])

    features = parsed_features['features']

    return features, image

random_features = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([72, 432], tf.float32))
random_images = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([72, 112, 112, 3]))

datasets = []
for _ in filenames:
    datasets.append(tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(_).map(_parse_function))

dataset_ziped = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset.zip((datasets[0], datasets[1], datasets[2], datasets[3],
      datasets[4], datasets[5], datasets[6], datasets[7], datasets[8]))
#dataset = dataset_ziped.repeat(num_epoch)
dataset = dataset_ziped.batch(batch_size)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next() # This has shape: [9, 2]

features = tf.concat((next_batch[0][0], next_batch[1][0], next_batch[2][0], next_batch[3][0],
                      next_batch[4][0], next_batch[5][0], next_batch[6][0], next_batch[7][0],
                      next_batch[8][0]), axis=0)
features = tf.reshape(features, shape=[9, 8, 432]) # where 8 * 9 = 72
features = tf.transpose(features, perm=[1, 0, 2]) # shape becomes: [8, 9, 432]
features = tf.reshape(features, shape=[72, 432]) # Now frames will be: 1st frame from 1st video, second from second video...

images = tf.concat((next_batch[0][1], next_batch[1][1], next_batch[2][1], next_batch[3][1],
                    next_batch[4][1], next_batch[5][1], next_batch[6][1], next_batch[7][1],
                    next_batch[8][1]), axis=0)
images = tf.reshape(images, shape=[9, 8, 112, 112, 3])
images = tf.transpose(images, perm=[1, 0, 2, 3, 4])
images = tf.reshape(images, shape=[72, 112, 112, 3])

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize `iterator` with training data.
    sess.run(init_op)

    for _ in range(num_epoch):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)

        # This while loop will run indefinitly until the end of the first epoch
        while True:
            try:
                lst = []
                features_np = sess.run([features])[0] # since the output is always: (1, 72, 432)

                for f in features_np:
                    lst.append(f[0])

            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('errorrrrr')
```

So, since the number of samples is no longer 72, I run into an error at line:

```
features = tf.reshape(features, shape=[9, 8, 432]) # where 8 * 9 = 72
```

So, I need a way to handle this error. I tried assertion as follows:

```
assert_op = tf.Assert(tf.equal(tf.shape(features[0]), batch_size * 9), [features])
with tf.control_dependencies([assert_op])... after features = tf.concat...
```

And it didn't work. I tried tf.cond as follows (and it didn't work as well):

```
tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.shape(features)[0], batch_size * 9),
        lambda: tf.assign(random_features, features),
        lambda: tf.assign(random_features, random_features))

features = tf.reshape(random_features, shape=[9, 8, 432]) # where 8 * 9 = 72
....
```

In conclusion, I need to way to iterate over epochs without interleaving samples from different iterations, and at the same time holding the issue of the feature while using the `reshape` function (where the batch size is less than 72 in my case).

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since the last batch is truncated, I created a temporary `variable` that will be assigned the value of the initial batch whenever the batch size is equal to my `batch_size` specified in the code. Therefore, once the size of the current batch is not longer equal to `batch_size`, I used the temporary batch that I have created. Here is the following solution:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2

num_epoch = 2
batch_size = 8 # This is set to 8 since
num_threads = 9
common = "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/AffectiveComputingNew/database/"
filenames = [(common + "train_1_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_2_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_3_db.tfrecords"),
     (common + "train_4_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_5_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_6_db.tfrecords"),
     (common + "train_7_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_8_db.tfrecords"), (common + "train_9_db.tfrecords")]

# Transforms a scalar string `example_proto` into a pair of a scalar string and
# a scalar integer, representing an image and its label, respectively.
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    features = {
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([432], tf.float32)
    }

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)

    # This is how we create one example, that is, extract one example from the database.
    image = tf.decode_raw(parsed_features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    # The height and the weights are used to
    height = tf.cast(parsed_features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(parsed_features['width'], tf.int32)

    # The image is reshaped since when stored as a binary format, it is flattened. Therefore, we need the
    # height and the weight to restore the original image back.
    image = tf.reshape(image, [height, width, 3])

    features = parsed_features['features']

    return features, image
# Here is the temp var that I will use whenever the return batch from the dataset doesn't have a size of batch_size * 9 mentioned above. 
random_features = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([72, 432], tf.float32))
random_images = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([72, 112, 112, 3], tf.uint8))

datasets = []
for _ in filenames:
    datasets.append(tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(_).map(_parse_function))

dataset_ziped = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset.zip((datasets[0], datasets[1], datasets[2], datasets[3],
      datasets[4], datasets[5], datasets[6], datasets[7], datasets[8]))
dataset = dataset_ziped.batch(batch_size)

iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_batch = iterator.get_next() # This has shape: [9, 2]

features = tf.concat((next_batch[0][0], next_batch[1][0], next_batch[2][0], next_batch[3][0],
                      next_batch[4][0], next_batch[5][0], next_batch[6][0], next_batch[7][0],
                      next_batch[8][0]), axis=0)
images = tf.concat((next_batch[0][1], next_batch[1][1], next_batch[2][1], next_batch[3][1],
                    next_batch[4][1], next_batch[5][1], next_batch[6][1], next_batch[7][1],
                    next_batch[8][1]), axis=0)

def get_features(features, images):
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(random_features, features), tf.assign(random_images, images)]):
        features = tf.reshape(features, shape=[9, 8, 432]) # where 8 * 9 = 72
        features = tf.transpose(features, perm=[1, 0, 2]) # shape becomes: [8, 9, 432]
        features = tf.reshape(features, shape=[72, 432]) # Now frames will be: 1st frame from 1st video, second from second video...

        images = tf.reshape(images, shape=[9, 8, 112, 112, 3])
        images = tf.transpose(images, perm=[1, 0, 2, 3, 4])
        images = tf.reshape(images, shape=[72, 112, 112, 3])
        return features, images

condition1 = tf.equal(tf.shape(features)[0], batch_size * 9)
condition2 = tf.equal(tf.shape(images)[0], batch_size * 9)

condition = tf.logical_and(condition1, condition2)

features, images = tf.cond(condition,
                           lambda: get_features(features, images),
                           lambda: get_features(random_features, random_images))

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize `iterator` with training data.
    sess.run(init_op)

    for _ in range(num_epoch):
        sess.run(iterator.initializer)

        # This while loop will run indefinitly until the end of the first epoch
        while True:
            try:
                lst = []
                features_np, images_np = sess.run([features, images])

                for f in features_np:
                    lst.append(f[0])

                print(lst)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('errorrrrr')
                break
```

Please note that I was always mentioning `batch_size * 9` since when zipping the datasets, that would create a sample data who's elements are fetched from 9 different datasets. Therefore, since I assigned the batch_size to be 8, to have 72 samples, I took 8 * 9.